# select distinct of one column from multiple columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this query.

```
select Leaf_id,product_id_x,product_id_y,count from table;
```

what i am looking for is select all the values for distinct Leaf_id.

So i tried

```
select Leaf_id,product_id_x,product_id_y,count from table group by Leaf_id;
```

but getting this error.

```
SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
 'table.product_id_x' which is not functionally dependent on columns in 
GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by")
```

should i do grouping on all the columns
?

Comment: If you notice, `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` is enabled. To get distinct based on one column disable this using `SET sql_mode = ''`

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: `only_full_group_by` is highly recommended.

Comment: @Viki888, no that's not recommended. see @jarlh comment. `only_full_group_by` enables it to compatible with other RDBMS types

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use `distinct` keyword

```
select distinct Leaf_id,product_id_x,product_id_y,`count` from `table`;
```

Comment: would it select distinct values from all the columns?

Comment: All selected columns.

Comment: @SRingne, distinct of all selected columns in combination

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all values for each column, then use aggregation functions.  Perhaps you want `group_concat()`:

```
select Leaf_id, group_concat(distinct product_id_x),
       group_concat(distinct product_id_y),
       group_concat(distinct count)
from table
group by leaf_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
 max(Leaf_id) as Leaf_ID
,product_id_x
,product_id_y
,count

from table

group by product_id_x, product_id_y, count
```

This might help? Obviously

```
Min(Leaf_ID) as Leaf_ID
```

would work a well.

Hope this helps

Comment: Invalid GROUP BY. (The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!)

Comment: I meant to group by everything else... Oops!